# TextboxFor Posting Value when readonly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a TextBox using the html helper methods in my View.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

I would like this textbox to retain its value when posted, even if a malicious user tries to change it.

I am testing my code in IE, and can easily use the developer tools to remove the attribute "readonly".

Is there any implementation in MVC3 to retain values for the textboxes when posting? I am trying to avoid going to the database to get the original value.

Comment: Have you considered simply not updating that particular value?

Comment: I want that value to go to a different controller, and perform actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any implementation in MVC3 to retain values for the textboxes when posting?

No, there isn't. This is not possible. If you have sent the value up to the client you can no longer trust it. As you have already discovered it is trivial for the user to change the value of hidden and readonly fields. So if those values aren't meant to be modified by the user they should not even be part of the HTML. You should keep them on the server. Well, actually you could display them as readonly fields just for information to the user but when the form is submitted never use this value but use the real value that is stored on your server (maybe in a database or whatever persistent store you are using).

Comment: this is why i prefer presentation models. this way I don't care if those values are reposted.

Comment: could you please tell me what presentation models are?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try serializing everything you want to retain, encrypt it using a key only known to the server and store the encrypted value into a hidden input. You can still display the non-encrypted values in the form controllers, but at the server side, you will use the encrypted value send via the hidden input for actual processing. This way if a malicious user changes the standard inputs, it doesn’t matter, coz you will be using the encrypted copy.. A bit of a sidewinder, I know and its similar to how web forms maintains viewstate across posts.. Cheers

Comment: I am definitely interested in your approach. I will look into that.